# Update nested array element if exists

Tags: arrays, swift

The following code works great in that it finds if I have an element within a nested array. If such an element does not exist the code inserts it.

I'm struggling to find a way to remove an existing element if it already exists so I can then insert an updated version of it.

Perhaps there is even a better way to just update the existing element without removing it first?

```
if insertSolution.contains(where: { $0.resourceName == name }) {
  //remove $0
  //insert new resource
  print("Already inserted. Update needed!")
} else {
  insertSolution.append(solution);
  print("New solution. Insert needed!");
}
```

Comment: does the job https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994722-firstindex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine the *index* of an existing element, and update that
element if it exists, otherwise append:

```
if let idx = insertSolution.firstIndex(where: { $0.resourceName == name }) {
    // Update existing element:
    insertSolution[idx] = ...
} else {
    // Append new element:
    insertSolution.append(...);
}
```